# What is the best way to validate incoming json data using Jackson in Spring boot?

Tags: xml, spring-boot, jackson, xjc

I am using spring boot v 2.7.1 with Java 17. I define how data structure should look like in xsd. Then I use xjc to convert it to Java classes. The xjc markers mandatory elements with annotation `@XmlElement(required = true)` I need to validate these elements when deserialising with Jackson into Java classes. What’s the best and the easiest to do it? Jackson deserialise json message.

I’ve tried this bean to enable spring boot to register the annotations.

```
@Bean
public Module jaxbModule(){
 return new JaxbAnnotationModule();
}
```

Comment: you can use the Bean Validation API (JSR-303) to perform validation on incoming JSON data during deserialization with Jackson.

Comment: @Daqs Can u please share an example?

Comment: The validation is done using the namespace (schema) in the XML.  The OPs who created the XML should validate using the schema so OPs who receive the XML are able to parse.  I assume the xml is embedded in the json data.

Comment: @jdweng So if I understand it correctly, the the correct way to validate data is on the consumer side when creating the message?

Comment: The validation should come from the producer.  The consumer doesn't have to validate if data is know to be good, but there is nothing wrong with consumer doing a second check.

Comment: @jdweng Ok so what would u recommend in my scenario. I have to validate incoming data from producer, it comes in json. Jackson deserialises it to Java classes. These classes have @XmlElement(required=true), but when deserialising there is no check for these items

Comment: Aren't the Xml objects in json just strings?  To validate you would need to create an XML object and validate using the schema.

Comment: So there is no easy way to validate data when deserialising them by Jackson from json to Java classes?